# Mismatched types on handling Value enum

Tags: enums, rust, rpc, matching

I am trying to use the `rmp_rpc` Rust libary to make a server that accepts commands from a client that is written in Python. I am modifying [this](https://github.com/little-dude/rmp-rpc/blob/master/examples/server.rs) example to reach my goal.

How can I handle an argument of varying type (integer/string/boolean) into a match statement without getting a "mismatched types; expected i32, found enum 'rmp_rpc::Value'" error? For each method the params types might be different.

```
fn handle_request(&mut self, method: &str, params: &[Value]) -> Self::RequestFuture {
        match method {
            "sum" => Methods::sum(params[0], params[1]),
            "draw" => Methods::draw(params),
            "conc" => Methods::concatenate(params[0], params[1])
        }
```

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either perform your type checking here at the call site, or defer type-checking to the callee (the `Echo::<whatever>` methods).

At the call site:

```
match method {
    "sum" => Echo::sum(params[0].as_u64().expect("expected u64"), params[1].as_u64().expect("expected u64")),
    "draw" => Echo::draw(params), // <-- this must continue to be passed as &[Value]
    "concatenate => Echo::conc(params[0].as_str().expect("expected str"), params[1].as_str().expect("expected str"))
}
```

In the callee:

```
impl Echo {
    pub fn sum(v1: Value, v2: Value) -> u64 {
        let v1 = v1.as_u64().expect("expected u64");
        let v2 = v2.as_u64().expect("expected u64");

        v1 + v2
    }
}
```

This is [based on the documentation I could find available](https://docs.rs/rmp-rpc/0.2.0/rmp_rpc/enum.Value.html#method.as_u64).

Comment: Thank you! This worked. After that I only had to edit the function definitions so that their output be the same. Otherwise I had a "match arm with an incompatible type" error

Answer (score 0):

What I did according to Simon was 
`match method {
  "sum" => Methods::sum(params[0].as_u64().expect("expected u64"), params[1].as_u64().expect("expected u64")),
  "conc" => Methods::concatenate(params[0].as_str().expect("expected str"), params[1].as_str().expect("expected str")),
  "draw" => Methods::draw(params),
  _ => Err("invalid argument".into())
}` 

but also fix each function's output to a Result<'Value, Value>
in order to avoid incompatible type error